# Proof regarding Big-Oh

Tags: proof-writing, asymptotics

For a while I've been trying to prove:
$$4n^4 - 2n^3 + 2n^2 -2n \not \in \mathcal{O}{(2n^3 - 1.5n + 2)}$$

I'm having a hard time trying to begin this proof. I've done simpler Big-Oh proofs but I can't really figure out how to begin this one. I'm trying to prove this WITHOUT calculus. Is that even possible?

Comment: Oh apologies. It's a typo. It's fixed now.

Comment: Can you prove $n^4\notin\mathcal O(n^3)$ ?

Comment: Yeah I am able to prove that. But can I just say "Ignore lower order terms" in such a proof? We have just been introduced to the notion of Big-Oh so I thought this will be an over-simplification.

Answer (score 1):

One strategy:

1. Prove LHS is $\Theta(n^4)$
2. Prove RHS is $\Theta(n^3)$
3. Prove $n^4$ is not $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$.

Answer (score 0):

You "ignore the lower order terms" the same way you do in evaluating a limit at infinity of a ratio of polynomials...

Let $f(n) = 4n^4 - 2n^3 + 2n^2 -2n$ and $g(n) = 2n^3 - 1.5n + 2$.  We wish to show $f \not \in O(g)$.

Suppose, for contradiction, $f \in O(g)$.  Then there is an $N$ and an $M$ such that 
$$  n \geq N \implies |f(n)|\leq M |g(n)|  \text{.}  $$
In particular, this says $|f|/|g|$ is bounded for all sufficiently large arguments.  Then \begin{align*}
\frac{|f(n)|}{|g(n)|} &= \frac{|4n^4 - 2n^3 + 2n^2 -2n|}{|2n^3 - 1.5n + 2|}  \\
    &= \frac{|n^3| \,|4n - 2 + 2/n -2/n^2|}{|n^3|\,|2 - 1.5/n^2 + 2/n^3|}  \\
    &= \frac{|4n - 2 + 2/n -2/n^2|}{|2 - 1.5/n^2 + 2/n^3|}  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Suppose $n > \max\{0,N\}$, then the numerator is $> 4n - 2 - 2/n^2 > 4n-3$ and the denominator is $< 2+2$.  (In the one case, we ignore a positive contribution and exaggerate the fractions; in the other we ignore a negative contribution and exaggerate a fraction.)  Consequently, this fraction is at least $\frac{4n-3}{4} = n - \frac{3}{4}$, which is not bounded by any choice of $M$ as $n$ increases.  In particular, for $n > M+1$, $M$ does not bound $|f|/|g|$.  With this contradiction, $f \not \in O(g)$.